# How to set up a icon for a web application in java?

Tags: tomcat6, favicon

I have a web application running on tomcat. I want to setup a favicon for it. Where should i place it in the tomcat web application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you place a file called `favicon.ico` in your document root (`/`), it will automatically used.

Comment: @sushil: afaik, this is the way to do it for any web app, not just java :-)

Comment: @Jacco @Ant already tried it. I was also thinking same. But this is not working.

Answer (score 7):

Just to summarize answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8092503/1192987), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6641087/1192987)) up:

1. Name your icon `favicon.ico` and put it into the `/src/main/webapp` (for Maven layout) or `/WebContent` (for standard Eclipse layout).
2. Specify icon in every HTML page (or master page if present):

   `<head>`
   `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"/>`
   `</head>`
3. Refresh project / clean/restart server / refresh page with Ctrl+F5 (to skip browser's cache).

Answer (score 1):

This might be useful, but I don't remember having had to do it:

http://stonescape.net/roller/xtian/entry/implementing_favicon_ico_with_tomcat

Comment: what version of tomcat you got?

Comment: i just checked. for my blog i have one, and its under http://blog.maxant.co.uk/pebble/favicon.ico - the URL you type to see the blog is http://blog.maxant.co.uk/pebble/ - ie. the icon is in the root dir of the webapp.  under conf/web.xml i have NO mapping as suggested in the above article.  its running on tomcat 5.5.9 and i can see the icon in firefox.  can you see it?

Comment: that what , I am not able to see the icon. I have all what you are mentioning here.

Comment: @sushil: you mean you can't see the icon at my blog?  Which browser are you using?

Comment: I can see icon at ur blog. Not at mine.

Comment: hmm... then I dont know what to say...  so if you type: http://localhost:portNumber/favicon.ico or http://localhost:portNumber/theNameOfYourApp/favicon.ico into your browser, then you don't see the icon loaded?  That means that it's not in the right place.